# After Effects rotate hotkey

Tags: after-effects

Was looking for hotkeys to ease working in AE and found a bunch but for rotation, it only allows 1 or 10 degrees at a time.

Is there any hotkey to rotate the layer by 0.1 or 0.5 degrees?

Or is there any way to hack/customize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this script rotates the currently selected layer(s) 0.1 degree clockwise. Save it as rotate_0.1_cw.jsx and then [add it to a hotkey](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/scripts.html). Change the line `var inc = 0.1;` to `var inc = -0.1;` save as rotate_0.1_ccw.jsx and add it to another hotkey. Rinse, repeat.

```
// @target aftereffects
(function () {
    var theComp = app.project.activeItem;
    if (theComp) {
        var theLayers = theComp.selectedLayers;
        for (var i = 0; i < theLayers.length; i++) {
            if (theLayers[i].transform.rotation.numKeys) {
                theLayers[i].transform.rotation.setValueAtTime(theComp.time, theLayers[i].transform.rotation.value + 0.1);
            } else {
                theLayers[i].transform.rotation.setValue(theLayers[i].transform.rotation.value + 0.1);
            }
        }
    }
})()
```